# share created with net use with other account than login accout disappear

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, user-accounts, net-use

We have the problem that we are trying to create a share with `net use` with a different account than the actual login account on a Win7 PC.

e.g.
login account is "user" (the actual account used to logon to the PC)
account used for our software "admin" (the account which is used to run our application)

the SMB share is created with the credentials of the login account: `net use \\server\path`

then, later, when an operator copies a file to this share via our application, the share is no longer present.

This can be simulated on any windows PC with 2 accounts: a login account, and a different account as follows:

- login with user account
- open a command box as user 2 (e.g. run as admin)
- net use \server\path
- net use (verify the share is created)

then
- open a new command box, again as user 2 (e.g. run as admin)
- net use (and now verify that the share is no longer available to this account)

Strangely enough, this works *fine* when you do this exercise with the login account.

Advice/help is much appreciated!

Comment: Verify all permissions to the share.  Are we talking about domain user accounts or just local user accounts?

Comment: Both are local accounts. The share is read&write enabled for "everybody". (fullcontrol even,. for everybody)

Comment: These users accounts only have read and write permissions. What about the `List Folder Contents` permission?

Comment: The problem is that when the share is created the admin account, the share is no longer visible when I open a new command box (both command boxes opened as admin). When I create the share, I can write to the share, on either account. So it's not a permissions issue, that I know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this how-to should help: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/36841-map-an-admin-network-drive-as-a-non-admin-user

Comment: tried the solution, no luck though. Thx for the help though!